# Is complete list of Demons sequentially killed by Devi as per Devi mahatyam available?

Tags: devi, shakti, shaktism

Is there Full/complete sequential list of Demons that were killed by Devi and which devi swarupam killed which demon as per Devi mahatyam? Why only Devi had to kill the demons? Why not trimurthis not involved or supported?

Why demons agreed to battle with Stree murthi?

Answer (score 4):

***A partial answer.***

Apart from eliminating main demon leaders, Devi also eliminated many ordinary demon soldiers, whose names were not given in Durga Saptasati aka [Devi Mahatmya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi_Mahatmya). Hence, providing complete list of demons eliminated by Devi, **according to Devi Mahatmya**, may not be possible.

---

The remaining questions are:

> - Why only Devi had to kill the demons?
> - Why not trimurthis not involved or supported?
> - Why demons agreed to battle with Stree murthi?

---

According to [2nd chapter](https://www.templepurohit.com/durga-saptashati/durga-saptashati-chapter-2/) of **Devi Mahatmya**, the energies of all Gods, including Shiva, Vishnu, Brahma, Indra, etc, came out of them, and got consolidated in the form of Devi.

> तोऽतिकोपपूर्णस्य चक्रिणो वदनात्ततः। निश्‍चक्राम महत्तेजो ब्रह्मणः
>   शंकरस्य च॥१०॥
>
> अन्येषां चैव देवानां शक्रादीनां शरीरतः। निर्गतं सुमहत्तेजस्तच्चैक्यं
>   समगच्छत॥११॥
>
> The issued forth a great light from the face of Vishnu who was full of
>   intense anger, and from that of Brahma and Siva too. From the bodies
>   of Indra and other devas also sprang forth a very great light. And
>   (all) this light united together.

All the Gods gave their respective weapons to Devi.

> शूलं शूलाद्विनिष्कृष्य ददौ तस्यै पिनाकधृक्। चक्रं च दत्तवान् कृष्णः
>   समुत्पाद्य* स्वचक्रतः॥२०॥
>
> शङ्‌खं च वरुणः शक्तिं ददौ तस्यै हुताशनः। मारुतो दत्तवांश्‍चापं
>   बाणपूर्णे तथेषुधी॥२१॥
>
> The bearer of Pinaka (Siva) drawing forth a trident from his own
>   trident presented it to her; and Vishnu bringing forth a discus out of
>   his own discus gave her. Varuna gave her a conch, Agni a spear; and
>   Maruta gave a bow as well as two quivers full of arrows.

---

After the elimination of Mahishasura by Devi, the devas said:

> भगवत्या कृतं सर्वं न किंचिदवशिष्यते॥३४॥
>
> यदयं निहतः शत्रुरस्माकं महिषासुरः। यदि चापि वरो देयस्त्वयास्माकं
>   महेश्‍वरि॥३५॥
>
> संस्मृता संस्मृता त्वं नो हिंसेथाः परमापदः। यश्‍च मर्त्यः
>   स्तवैरेभिस्त्वां स्तोष्यत्यमलानने॥३६॥
>
> ‘Since our enemy, this Mahishasura, has been slain by Bhagavati (i.e
>   you) everything has been accomplished, and nothing remains to be done.
>   And ***if a boon is to be granted to us by you, O Maheshvari, whenever we
>   think of you again, destroy our direct calamities***.

And, Devi agreed to this wish.

---

When Shumba and Nishumba defeated Devas, the latter prayed to Devi.  Devi took the of beautiful form.  Knowing the beauty of Devi, Shumba and Nishumba sent messengers to Devi for choose them as her partner.

Then Devi says that since she took an oath of choosing a partner, who defeats her, Shumba and Nishumba had to fight with her.

> किं त्वत्र यत्प्रतिज्ञातं मिथ्या तत्क्रियते कथम्।
>   श्रूयतामल्पबुद्धित्वात्प्रतिज्ञा या कृता पुरा॥११९॥
>
> यो मां जयति संग्रामे यो मे दर्पं व्यपोहति। यो मे प्रतिबलो लोके स मे
>   भर्ता भविष्यति॥१२०॥
>
> Hear what promise I had made already out of foolishness. “He who
>   conquers me in battle, removes my pride and is my match in strength in
>   the world shall be my husband.”

---

That was how the demons were dragged into the battlefield by Devi.

The main demons that were killed by Devi were:

Mahishasura, Dhumralochana, Chanda, Munda, Raktabija, Nishumba and Shumba.

Answer (score 3):

As the reasons r already cleared by Shrimannarayanji.
I would continue wid the complete list of asurs, daityas, n itr yonis devi slayed here.

**Madhu & Kaithaba** in Pratham Charitra

**Chamar, Chikshur, Udagra, Mahahanu, Asilom, Bashkal, Parivarit, Bidal, Karal, Uddhata, Tamra, Andhaka, Uddhata, Ugrasya, Ugravirya,Durdhar, Durmukha,and finally Mashishasur** in Madhyam Charitra.

**50 senaptis frm Kotivirya Kula, 100 Senapatis of Dhaumra Kula, Kalak, Daurhad, Maurya, Kalkey,
And finally Shumbha Nishumbha** in Uttam Charitra.

Later devi, in the 11th chapter of Saptashati promises to kill,**the decendants of asur Viprachita, Arunasur, Durgamasur, Bhim,Shumbha Nishumbha** in future.

If someone is looking for the shlokas mentioning each death then here they are,

**Chapter 1st,Killing Madhu and Kaithaba**,

> खड्‌गं चक्रगदेषुचापपरिघाञ्छूलं भुशुण्डीं शिरः
> शङ्खं संदधतीं करैस्त्रिनयनां सर्वाङ्गभूषावृताम्।
> नीलाश्मद्युतिमास्यपाददशकां सेवे महाकालिकां
> यामस्तौत्स्वपिते हरौ कमलजो हन्‍तुं मधुं कैटभम्॥
> I resort to Mahakali, who has ten faces, ten legs and holds in her hands the sword, disc, mace, arrows, bow, club, spear, missile, human head and conch, who is three-eyed, adorned with ornaments on all her limbs, and luminous like a blue jewel, and whom Brahma extolled in order to destroy **Madhu and Kaitabha**, when Vishnu was in (mystic) sleep.

One may think if Vishnu killed Madhu and his brother so why Mahakai is linked and why is it mentioned in Saptashati?
The further shloka explains it,

> प्रबोधं च जगत्स्वामी नीयतामच्युतो लघु॥86॥
> बोधश्‍च क्रियतामस्य हन्‍तुमेतौ महासुरौ॥87॥
> एवं स्तुता तदा देवी तामसी तत्र वेधसा॥89॥
> When Brahma eulogized **Tamasi devi** with the intention of waking up Vishnu the lords of all worlds, to kill madhu and kaithbha....

> पञ्चवर्षसहस्राणि बाहुप्रहरणो विभुः।
> तावप्यतिबलोन्मत्तौ महामायाविमोहितौ॥94॥
> पञ्चवर्षसहस्राणि बाहुप्रहरणो विभुः।
> तावप्यतिबलोन्मत्तौ महामायाविमोहितौ॥94॥
> Thereupon the all-pervading Bhagavan Vishnu got up and fought with the asuras for five thousand years, using his own arms as weapons. And they, frenzied with their exceeding power, and **deluded by Mahamaya**, exclaimed to Vishnu, '
> Ask a boon from us.'

Thus, Vishnu could kill Madhu and Kaithaba only after Yognidra left Vishnu's body and in war after Mahamaya deluded the duo Asuras.

**2nd chapter where Mahishasur asks various Armies and their leaders to lead a war against Devi and aid him** (But we all know all of these asurs were killed in war, thou there is no mention if devi killing Asilom, yet it is mentioned in Devi Bhagwatam, but still these both puranas r from different kalpa, so itihas may differ),

> शस्त्रास्त्रैर्बहुधा मुक्तैरादीपितदिगन्तरम्।
> महिषासुरसेनानीश्‍चिक्षुराख्यो महासुरः॥40॥
> युयुधे चामरश्‍चान्यैश्‍चतुरङ्‌गबलान्वितः।
> रथानामयुतैः षड्‌भिरुदग्राख्यो महासुरः॥41॥
> अयुध्यतायुतानां च सहस्रेण महाहनुः।
> पञ्चाशद्‌भिश्‍च नियुतैरसिलोमा महासुरः॥42॥
> अयुतानां शतैः षड्‌भिर्बाष्कलो युयुधे रणे।
> गजवाजिसहस्रौघैरनेकैः* परिवारितः*॥43॥
> वृतो रथानां कोट्या च युद्धे तस्मिन्नयुध्यत।
> बिडालाख्योऽयुतानां च पञ्चाशद्भिरथायुतैः॥44॥
> युयुधे संयुगे तत्र रथानां परिवारितः।
> अन्ये च तत्रायुतशो रथनागहयैर्वृताः॥45॥
> युयुधुः संयुगे देव्या सह तत्र महासुराः।
> कोटिकोटिसहस्रैस्तु रथानां दन्तिनां तथा॥46॥
> Mahisasura's general, a great asura named **Ciksura and Chamara**, attended by forces comprising four parts, and other (asuras) fought. A great asura named **Udagra with sixty thousand chariots**, and **Mahahanu with ten millions (of chariots)** gave battle. **Asiloman**, another great asura, **with fifteen millions (of chariots)**, and **Baskala with six millions** fought in that battle. **Privarita** with many **thousands of elephants and horses**, and surrounded by **ten millions of chariots**, fought in that battle. An asura named **Bidala** fought in that battle surrounded with **five hundred crores of chariots**. And other great asuras, thousands in number, surrounded with chariots, elephants and horses fought with the Devi in that battle.

**3rd Chapter, Killing Mahishasur and his various yodhas aiding him in war**,

On slaying of **Chikshur**, the senapati of Mahishasur the shloka says,

> दृष्ट्‍वा तदापतच्छूलं देवी शूलममुञ्चत।
> तच्छूलं शतधा तेन नीतं स च महासुरः॥10।।
> 0n Seeing that pike coming upon her, the Devi hurled her pike that shattered his pike into a
> hundred fragments and the great asura himself.

On killing of other yodhas,

> ततो वेगात् खमुत्पत्य निपत्य च मृगारिणा।
> करप्रहारेण शिरश्‍चामरस्य पृथक्कृतम्॥16॥
> Then the lion, springing up quickly to the sky, and descending, severed **Chamar's** head with a blow from its paw.
> उदग्रश्‍च रणे देव्या शिलावृक्षादिभिर्हतः।
> दन्तमुष्टितलैश्‍चैव करालश्‍च निपातितः॥17॥
> And **Udagra** was killed in the battle by the Devi with stones, trees and the like, and **Karala** also stricken down by her teeth and fists and slaps.
> देवी क्रुद्धा गदापातैश्‍चूर्णयामास चोद्धतम्।
> बाष्कलं भिन्दिपालेन बाणैस्ताम्रं तथान्धकम्॥18॥
> Enraged, the Devi ground **Uddhata** to powder with the blows of her club, and killed **Baskala** with a dart and destroyed **Tamra** and **Andhaka** with arrows.
> उग्रास्यमुग्रवीर्यं च तथैव च महाहनुम्।
> त्रिनेत्रा च त्रिशूलेन जघान परमेश्वरी॥19॥
> The three-eyed Supreme Isvari killed **Ugrasya** and **Ugravirya** and **Mahahanu** also with her trident.
> बिडालस्यासिना कायात्पातयामास वै शिरः।
> दुर्धरं दुर्मुखं चोभौ शरैर्निन्ये यमक्षयम्।।20।।
> With her sword she struck down **Bidala's** head from his body, and dispatched both **Durdhara** and **Durmudha** to the abode of Death with her arrows.

Finally Killing **Mahishasur**,

> अर्धनिष्क्रान्त एवासौ युध्यमानो महासुरः।
> तया महासिना देव्या शिरश्छित्त्वा निपातितः।।42।।
> Fighting thus with his half-revealed form, the great asura was laid by the Devi who **struck off his head** with her great sword.

**6th Chapter the death of Dhumralochana and his army**,

> इत्युक्तः सोऽभ्यधावत्तामसुरो धूम्रलोचनः।
> हुंकारेणैव तं भस्म सा चकाराम्बिका ततः॥13॥
> Thus told, the asura **Dhumralocana** rushed towards her and thereupon Ambika reduced him to ashes with a mere heave of the sound 'hum'.
> क्षणेन तद्‌बलं सर्वं क्षयं नीतं महात्मना।
> तेन केसरिणा देव्या वाहनेनातिकोपिना॥19॥
> 19. In a moment all that army was destroyed by that high-spirited and exceedingly enraged lion who bore the Devi.

**7th Chapter, explaining the Chanda Munda death**,

> उत्थाय च महासिं हं देवी चण्डमधावत।
> गृहीत्वा चास्य केशेषु शिरस्तेनासिनाच्छिनत्।।20।।
> Then the Devi, mounting upon her great lion, rushed at **Chanda**, and seizing him by his hair, **severed his head** with her sword.
> अथ मुण्डोऽभ्यधावत्तां दृष्ट्‌वा चण्डं निपातितम्।
> तमप्यपातयद्भूमौ सा खड्गाभिहतं रुषा॥21॥
> 21. Seeing Chanda laid low, **Munda** also rushed at her. She felled him also the ground, **striking him with her sword** in her fury.

**8th chapter, where Shumbha asks Raktbeeja and various Daitya, Danavas and others to join** (Whole army and Raktbeej are killed),

> अद्य सर्वबलैर्दैत्याः षडशीतिरुदायुधाः।
> कम्बूनां चतुरशीतिर्निर्यान्तु स्वबलैर्वृताः॥4।।
> Now let the **eighty-six asuras** - upraising their weapons - with all their forces, and the **eighty-four Kambus**, surrounded by their own forces, go out.
> कोटिवीर्याणि पञ्चाशदसुराणां कुलानि वे।                             शतं कुलानि धौम्राणां निर्गच्छन्तु ममाज्ञया॥5॥
> Let the **fifty asura families of Kotiviryas** and the **hundred families of Dhaumras** go forth at my command.
> कालका दौर्हृद मौर्याः कालकेयास्तथासुराः।
> युद्धाय सज्जा निर्यान्तु आज्ञया त्वरिता मम॥6॥
> 'Let the asurasa **Kalakas, Daurhrdas, the Mauryas** and the **Kalakeyas** hasten at my command and march forth ready for battle.'
> नीरक्तश्‍च महीपाल रक्तबीजो महासुरः।
> ततस्ते हर्षमतुलमवापुस्त्रिदशा नृप॥62॥
> Stricken with a multitude of weapons and bloodless, the great asura **(Raktabija)** fell on the ground, O King.

**9th Chapter, mention slaying Nishumbha**,

> शूलहस्तं समायान्तं निशुम्भममरार्दनम्।
> हृदि विव्याध शूलेन वेगाविद्धेन चण्डिका॥34॥
> 34. As **Nisumbha**, the afflictor of the devas, was advancing with the dart in hand, Chandika **pierced him in the heart** with a swiftly hurled dart.
> भिन्नस्य तस्य शूलेन हृदयान्निःसृतोऽपरः।
> महाबलो महावीर्यस्तिष्ठेति पुरुषो वदन्॥35॥
> 35. From his (Nisumbha's) heart that was pierced by the dart, issued forth another person of great strength and valour, exclaiming (at the Devi) 'Stop.'
> तस्य निष्क्रामतो देवी प्रहस्य स्वनवत्ततः।                                 शिरश्चिच्छेद खड्‌‍गेन ततोऽसावपतद्भुवि॥36॥
> 36. Then the Devi, laughing aloud, **severed the head of him**, who issued forth, with her sword. Thereupon he fell to the ground.

10th Chapter shloka mentioning killing of Shumbha,

> तमायान्तं ततो देवी सर्वदैत्यजनेश्‍वरम्।
> जगत्यां पातयामास भित्त्वा शूलेन वक्षसि॥26॥
> Seeing that lord of all the daitya-folk approaching, the Devi, **piercing him on the chest** with a dart, threw him down on the earth.

**The 11th Chapter, where she promises to kill various aruras in future**,

> वैवस्वतेऽन्तरे प्राप्ते अष्टाविंशतिमे युगे।
> शुम्भो निशुम्भश्‍चैवान्यावुत्पत्स्येते महासुरौ॥41॥
> When the twenty-eighth age has arrived during the period of Avaisvsvata Manu, two other great asuras, **Sumbha and Nisumbha** will be born.
> नन्दगोपगृहे* जाता यशोदागर्भसम्भवा।
> ततस्तौ नाशयिष्यामि विन्ध्याचलनिवासिनी॥42॥
> 'Then born from the womb of Yasoda, in the home of cowherd Nanda, and dwelling on the **Vindhya mountains, I will destroy them both**.
> पुनरप्यतिरौद्रेण रूपेण पृथिवीतले।
> अवतीर्य हनिष्यामि वैप्रचित्तांस्तु दानवान्॥43॥
> 'And again having incarnated in a very terrible form on the earth, I shall slay the danavas, who are the descendants of **Vipracitti**.
> तत्रैव च वधिष्यामि दुर्गमाख्यं महासुरम्॥49॥
> At that very period **I shall slay** the great asura named **Durgama**.
> पुनश्‍चाहं यदा भीमं रूपं कृत्वा हिमाचले॥50।।
> again, assuming a terrible form on the mountain Himalaya, **I shall destroy the raksasas** for the protection of the munis.

> यदारुणाख्यस्त्रैलोक्ये महाबाधां करिष्यति॥52॥
> When the (asura) named **Aruna** shall work great havoc in the three world.

> तदाहं भ्रामरं रूपं कृत्वाऽसंख्येयषट्‌पदम्।
> त्रैलोक्यस्य हितार्थाय वधिष्यामि महासुरम्॥53॥
> Having taken a (collective) bee-form, consisting of **innumerable bees, I shall slay the great asura** for the good of the world.

PS-Leave alone those unaccounted soldiers and chariots that devi destroyed by chewing & crushing them.

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**